# Creating a program in C++ that takes arguements from the command line

Tags: c++, command-line

I am trying to learn how to make a program in C++ that when you run it, you can tell it to run and specify options all in one line. For example you can do `ipconfig /all` in CMD and it runs ipconfig.exe with the option `/all`. Another example would be `shutdown -f` which tells the computer to shutdown with the option `-f`. For example, I want to make a program that downloads something from a URL and call it for example downloader. From command line one would type `downloader http://filehere.com /h` which would download the file with the /h option which I would define its property in my program. I don't want code or guides on how to make a downloader I am just trying to learn how to specify options like the /h.  Are there any guides out there that you know of and could post or any sample code? I have tried searching for guides, but I think I just don't know what this operation is actually called. Thank you.

Comment: For an alternative that (I think) is overly complex, but many people like, try [Boost.Program_options.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/program_options.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically define your `main` function to take two arguments: `int argc` and `char *argv[]`, such as:

```
int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
```

The first argument is how many parameters your program received, `argv` is a pointer to them. Note, this isn't mandated, you can name them whatever you want, but that's the convention. Just make sure your types match up.

You can use an option-parsing library, but those are often OS-specific. One simple way to check if you received a /h is:

```
int got_h = 0;
for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i)
   if (strcmp(argv[i], "/h") == 0)
      got_h = 1;
...
if (got_h)
   ...
```

`argv[argc]` will always be `NULL` to make iterating through them easier.

Some more information here: http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: Cool, thanks! Does this work for multiple arguments too? like `/h /f`?

Answer (score 2):

The `main` function takes two arguments, traditionally named `argc` and `argv`:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // ...
}
```

`argc` contains the number of arguments passed on the command line, and the `argv` array contains such arguments (with `argv[0]` being the name used to invoke your program); the last element of the `argv` array (i.e. `argv[argc]`) contains a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon your proficiency and inclination to use pointers, you may prefer to capture the command line as a `vector<string>`:

```
// UNTESTED CODE
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

  if(args.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Usage: downloader URL [options]\n";
    return 1;
  }
  if(std::find(args.begin(), args.end(), "/h") != args.end()) {
    option_h = true;
  }
  Download(args[0]);
}
```